# how to write a big string in a file in unix from shell terminal

Tags: shell, unix

I have a string like below which is a very big

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW7wo.png <-- it gets stuck like this on pasting the command

```
$str="Hello this question is related to print a big line in a Unix file. this line is very long having more than 300 characters inside it. When I am running the below commands its failing because on a Unix session if we paste big commands it does not get pasted properly";

echo "Hello this question is related to print a big line in a Unix file. this line is very long having more than 300 characters inside it. When I am running the below commands its failing because on a Unix session if we paste big commands it does not get pasted properly" > file.txt
```

this command is failing, also I tried

```
cat > file.dat <<_EOF_  "Hello this question is related to print a big line in a Unix file. this line is v.....aste big commands it does not get pasted properly"
_EOF_
```

But it's not successful. Screen is getting stuck since the full line is too big

I tried few options from 
http://www.guguncube.com/2140/unix-set-a-multi-line-text-to-a-string-variable-or-file-in-bash
but did not worked

Comment: Are you sure it is not a problem with the copy-paste buf? Can you try the same by holding down a key for some time to get a long line?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `bash`, first execute:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Then:

```
str=$(cat <<EOF
"Hello this question is related to print a big line in a Unix file. this line is very long having more than 300 characters inside it. When I am running the below commands its failing because on a Unix session if we paste big commands it does not get pasted properly"
EOF
)
```

To **direct** insert in file:

```
cat <<EOF >file.txt
"Hello this question is related to print a big line in a Unix file. this line is very long having more than 300 characters inside it. When I am running the below commands its failing because on a Unix session if we paste big commands it does not get pasted properly"
EOF
```

If every thing fails **broke** the line in pieces using the `escape` char.

```
cat <<EOF >file.txt
"Hello this question is related to print a big line in a Unix file. this \
line is very long having more than 300 characters inside it. When I am \
running the below commands its failing because on a Unix \
session if we paste big commands it does not get pasted properly"
EOF
```

Check: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: thanks, but I want this string to be written to a file say file.txt. where to include file.txt in this command. Also the command shared above when pasted on a terminal gets stuck

Comment: ``file.txt`` is included in my second command. Check the updated answer

Comment: hanks for the edit. the command you have pasted i tried the same (mentioned in original question) as well.. But if you actually try on a terminal the command gets stuck at "it does not get pasted" and words written after that i.e. "properly" is not printed . Can you try the command on unix session once... its not working http://i.imgur.com/4QjOLKC.png this is the problem.. i am on korne shell, also "shopt" command is not found on this version of unix

Comment: Type ``set -o vi``. To enable ``vi``  edition press the ``escape`` key of your keyboard  then ``v`` key and paste the provided command.

Comment: looks like the problem is on unix screen only 255 characters are allowed in a line so we need to think of a solution by which it can accept more than 255 characters, http://i.imgur.com/Bjd8Q1T.png its going till 255th character only

Comment: You can always use ``\`` to broke the line. See the ed answer